# Using local TFS workspace for non-VisualStudio source code

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

I am trying to use TFS storing non-VisualStudio source code. Working with Visual Studio 2012 and Microsoft's online Team Foundation Service.

I've setup a TeamProject and mapped its root to a local folder. All it contains at the moment is a BuildProcessTemplates folder in it. (which was created as part of the TeamProject)

I copied my source code externally (using windows explorer) into the TeamProject root folder on my hard drive and since my TFS workspace is NOT a server workspace but rather a local workspace, I was expecting VS to detect the folders/files and show them in Pending Changes window .... yet it doesn't.

Interestingly, new files in the root folder are detected as "Excluded Changes" but new folders are not detected.

What am I missing?

Comment: are there files in these new folders?

Comment: @betty: yes there are files and subfolders in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure the newly added folders contains files.

Are there any [**Detected changes**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx#add_existing_project) shown in the **Excluded Changes** section?
[image: Detected changes]

**Pending Changes** > **Detected changes** link > The **Promote Candidate Changes** dialog box appears > check the files you want and click **Promote**.

Comment: I've checked both excluded changes and detected changes. Both were showing no files at that moment. After that I used "Add Items to Folder" command in Source Control Explorer to add some files manually then it started detecting additional changes made in Windows Explorer. Curious... I don't know what caused the problem initially but now I cannot reproduce the situation. I'll keep trying and post here when I discover repro steps.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I have ever noticed nor expected TFS to automatically pick up files or folders added to a mapped directory as pending changes.

I always just add them manually using the 'Add existing items' option from the source control view.

It *may* actually do (or at least be *meant* to do) the auto-detection, but I can't say I've ever relied on it. I don't think it's something to fret too much about - adding them manually is easy enough, and the 'Add existing items' option is usually smart enough to show you which files are not already under source control, so even if you need to add even more files later, it shouldn't be too much extra effort.

Comment: "Local Workspace" feature introduced with TFS12 claims to do that.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't heard about that - I've just stuck to my old habits so I can't say I've paid enough attention to notice it either way with VS2012 either! Also being a bit of a Git aficionado, I have to say I somewhat prefer picking and choosing for myself, so it's not something I've given too much thought to.